# Is a "file://" path a URL?

Tags: url, path, uri

I sometimes see people refer to file system paths (POSIX/Windows) as both URIs and URLs. I'm no file system buff, but I have yet to find a file system path that conflicts with my understanding of the URL format. That is, of course, given that it includes the scheme name (e.g. file://localhost/path/to/file.txt).

File system paths are most definitely URIs - I mean, what's not - so everyone referring to file system paths as URIs is inside the safe zone. But is it safe to call them URLs?

If the URL was defined by a single (non-obsolete) RFC, rather than being comprised of half a dozen specialized ones, I wouldn't have to ask this question.

Comment: It is clearly not an absolute URL in the case of no schema. Also not all strings are URIs. As a trivial counter-example, `C:\Windows` is an invalid URL and an invalid URI.

Comment: Unfortunately, `file://` support may be silently removed from Chromium and Chromium-based browsers soon. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1299624

Answer (score 15):

`file` is a [registered URI scheme](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html) (for "Host-specific file names").

It links to [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), which is called "Uniform Resource Locators (URL)", in which `file` is [specified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10):

> A `file` URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> file://<host>/<path>
> ```

So yes, `file` URIs are URLs.

However, the subdivision from URIs into URLs, URNs and "Other" (like `data`) is not that useful anyway. FWIW, the [WHATWG URL spec](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#goals) tries to standardize on the term "URL" for all kind of URIs (even those that aren't URLs today, following the RFC). The [W3C Note "URIs, URLs, and URNs: Clarifications and Recommendations 1.0"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-uri-clarification-20010921/#uri-partitioning) tries to summarize the confusion about the terms:

> The body of documents (RFCs, etc) covering URI architecture, syntax, registration, etc., spans both the classical and contemporary periods. People who are well-versed in URI matters tend to use "URL" and "URI" in ways that seem to be interchangable. Among these experts, this isn't a problem. But among the Internet community at large, it is. People are not convinced that URI and URL mean the same thing, in documents where they (apparently) do. […]