# Error in importing JSON files in R using JSONLITE

Tags: json, r, import

I am using JSON lite to import JSON data in R but it giving me an error. I have seen the existing posts but couldn't find out the solution. Can anyone please help me in this ? Thanks

```
 library(jsonlite)
 data <- fromJSON('C:/Trajectories_DATA/017789_A3.json')

 Error: Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   C:/Trajectories_DATA/017789_A3.
                 (right here) ------^

     {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
       "features":
            [ 

            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry":
                {
                "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-0.254282663741729, 44.544465799932546]
                },
                "properties":
                {
                    "time": "5000",
                    "location": {
                      "building": "1",
                      "floor": "0"
                    }
                }
            },
             ....
  ]}
```

Comment: Just try tu use `"` insted of `'` but i'm not sure

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its still not working.

Comment: Ok then do `setwd("C:/Trajectories_DATA")` and then `data <- fromJSON("017789_A3.json")`

Comment: you can ty use `\\ `  instead of  `/`

Comment: `txt`is a a "JSON string, URL or file", not a path. So either add a file connection or read in the json using `readLines`. Just my guess.

Comment: `file://<host>/<path>` is an URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869526/is-a-file-path-a-url

Comment: Thank you Orhan and Martin for your help :) Good day .....